# Pass passwordlist to 7zip

Tags: shell-script, password, 7z, rar

I'm writing a shellscript to automate my 7zip, rar etc extraction tasks.
Normally JDownloader2 does this for me when I download files through it, but when I download files by hand I will still need to extract by myself. If the archives aren't password protected the script can run in the background just fine. But if the archives are password protected the extraction fails as I can't type in the passwords manually. So I wanted to know if there's a simple way of passing a password list to 7zip or unrar in the script so that it can read passwords from it line by line and so trying to get the right password.

Comment: If `7za` and `7z` stuffs doesn't provide a way to give a password in a file or as command line options, use `except` to automate password input.

Comment: s/`except`/`expect`/, I think...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my shell script that takes a password list and tests every line and extracts if one password was correct:

```
#!/bin/bash
passwordlist="/path/to/password-list"
outdir="/wherever"
cat "$passwordlist" | tr -d '\r' | while IFS= read -r PW 
do 
    if [[ $(7z l -p"$PW" "$1" 2>&1 | grep --count "ERROR") == 0 ]] 
    then
        echo "$PW" 
        7z x -p"$PW" -o"$outdir" -y "$1" 
        exit 0
    fi
done
```